# How can I call a php file passing some specific arguments?

Tags: php

I have a html page that calls a php file which loads data to a div according to some arguments that will be sent from the html file. I have seen many expessions like:

file.php?lang=en&year=2018&id=1&type=2

In my case, there are 10 arguments but in every call will be sent only a few of them. That's why I need something like the above line to be able to know what exactly is passed and what is not passed. I have seen many solutions having just spaces among arguments, like: file.php arg1 arg2 but that means all arguments must have a value, arg1 cannot be blank. In my case only a few of they will have value.

EDIT: I thought I was clear enough but I wasn't. I apologize. Both the html file and the php one are online in the same folder. I think that the best approach is file.php?lang=en&year=2018&id=1&type=2 but I don't know how to do it. There is no command line, just pages loaded by the browser.

Comment: `file.php arg1 arg2` is the approach for command-line usage, as it doesn't permit URL query strings. `file.php?lang=en&year=2018&id=1&type=2` is the query string approach you can use with a webserver. Which are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you need to expand on your question. As of now it is not very clear what you are doing.

Comment: If you're trying to do a CLI app, you can make arguments optional, i.e. `file.php --arg1=foo --arg3=bar`. It's kind of a pain to do it yourself (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php), but something like [`symfony/console`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html) makes it simple.

Comment: @ceejayoz Why not just use [getopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but add the arguments you need and in PHP access them with `$_GET`.  Or add all but leave the value blank for some: `?lang=en&year=&id=&type=2`

Comment: @Dharman That looks better. It's been years since I last DIYed it!

Comment: I edited my initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I understood from your explanation,

What you need is *isset* :

In your PHP file for each arguments check like this :

```
if (isset ($_GET['arg']))
{
 $arg = $_GET['arg'];
 // You can also set value to true or false to check if it's set like $arg = true;
}
```

Comment: In this case I will use something like: file.php?lang=en&year=2018&id=&type=2? (id is not set in this example)

Comment: I tried your solution and it is just what I wanted! Thanx a lot my friend!!